# Determining Conformal Map from Conformal Factor

Tags: image-processing

I am working on a project and need to apply a certain (Lorentzian) conformal transformation, $\psi:\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$, to a figure which I have generated numerically in Mathematica. I know that the new metric will be conformally flat. Hence, I know that the pullback metric will be $g_\text{ab}=\psi^*\eta_\text{ab}=f(t,x)^2 \eta_\text{ab}$ for some conformal factor $f(t,x)$. Fortunately, I know this conformal factor everywhere at least numerically. Is there an easy way to determine either the conformal map $\psi:\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ or its inverse given that I know the conformal factor, $f(t,x)$, at every point?

Or else is there some image processing way to stretch and squeeze portions of an image by various amounts?

**Details:**: The conformal factor is just some function which I have made up:

```
f[t_,x_] := 15+Sum[Sin[Sqrt[n]*(t+x*(-1)^n)-2n^2]*(10/n),{n,1,20}]
```

I am plotting it as a density plot:

```
DensityPlot[f[t,x],{x,-1.5,3},{t,-1,2},Frame->None,AspectRatio->3/4.5]
```

It looks like this. The orange regions ought to be expanded/bulged and the blue regions ought to be deflated/pinched. I know exactly how much each part of the image should be bulged and/or pinched by. But how do I carry out this transformation?

[image]

Comment: Please post all the map and all the functions with Mathematica code.

Comment: @cvgmt I have added the code and the figure to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal to get you started.

Create some function R^2->R with valleys and mountains. The gradient then defines the displacement of any point. It describes where the original pictures is stretched and where it is squeezed.

For illustration, define a the picture of a grid:

```
n = 40;
grid = Image@
  Graphics[
   Table[{Line[{{0, x}, {n, x}}], Line[{{x, 0}, {x, n}}]}, {x, 0, n}]]
```

[image]

Then define an arbitrary function and use it to define some distortion:

```
f[x_, y_] = -0.8  (Sqrt[(x - 0.5)^2 + (y - 0.5)^2]) + 
   1.5 ((x - 0.5)^2 + (y - 0.5)^2);
pl = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
dist[{x_, y_}] = {x, y} - 0.1 Grad[f[xx, yy], {xx, yy}] /. {xx -> x, 
    yy -> y};
```

[image]

Now we can use "dist" to distort the image "grid":

[image]